# Why will my if and els-if statement within my ruby method not work

Tags: ruby, class, if-statement, conditional-statements, attr-accessor

I am trying to create a ruby class with a method that takes ages into account. While the if elsif method works for producing 100 fruits for trees over the age of 5 and less than 10. Any tree over the age of 10 and less than 15 should produce 200 but don't?

```
def grow_fruits
    if @age <= 5
      @fruits = 0
    elsif @age < 10
      @fruits = 100
    elsif @age < 15
      @fruits = 200
    else
      @fruits = 0
    end
  end
```

I have tired @age <= 10 && @ < 15 but agai no response?

Comment: You need to specify in your question a concrete value for `@age` and what `@fruits` is set to for this value, and also describe what you would expect instead as a value for `@fruits`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code appears to work correctly:

```
# additional set variables before your code
@age=0
@fruits=0

# your code
def grow_fruits
  if @age <= 5
    @fruits = 0
  elsif @age < 10
    @fruits = 100
  elsif @age < 15
    @fruits = 200
  else
    @fruits = 0
  end
end
```

testing output:

```
2.7.2 :015 > grow_fruits
 => 0
2.7.2 :016 > @age=10
 => 10
2.7.2 :017 > grow_fruits
 => 200
2.7.2 :018 > @age=14
 => 14
2.7.2 :019 > grow_fruits
 => 200
2.7.2 :020 > @age=9
 => 9
2.7.2 :021 > grow_fruits
 => 100
```

personally, I hate using instance variables, in a "global variable" way, and would want to pass in the number that was being checked:

```
def grow_fruits(age=0)
  # remember triple-dots exclude the end value, useful for float comparison
  case age
  when 5...10
    100
  when 10...15
    200
  else
    0
  end
end
```

testing:

```
2.7.2 :035 > grow_fruits(0)
 => 0
2.7.2 :036 > grow_fruits(10)
 => 200
2.7.2 :037 > grow_fruits(14)
 => 200
2.7.2 :038 > grow_fruits(9)
 => 100
2.7.2 :039 > grow_fruits(21)
 => 0
```

if you really wanted to set the instance `@fruits` variable, you would be better off doing this:

```
@fruits = grow_fruits(@age)
```

Comment: `@fruits` is an instance variable.  `$fruits` would be a global variable.

Comment: although you are technically correct, it's essentially the same outside of the def. both are being used globally

Comment: Good suggestion, but there are a few easily-rectified problems. Firstly, and most importantly, `@grow_fruits(5)` is incorrect. (You need `when -Float::INFINITY..5 then 0` as the first `when`.). Secondly, you don't know that `@age` is an integer. I suggest `when 5...9` and `when 10...14` (three dots). Thirdly, I suggest your replace `if you really...this:` with `Then:`. (As noted, `@fruits` is an instance variable)...

Comment: ...Fourthly, in `def grow_fruits (age=1)` it's customary to have no spaces before `(` and there is no reason to having a default value). Lastly, I would replace everything before that line with "If you rerun your code you will find that it works correctly". What you now have adds nothing.

Comment: @cary in answer to "fourthly", it adds 2 little lines just above, setting the instance variables, since I have a suspicion that those were missing when he was testing.

Comment: as for the default in the incoming, if Jnoori is using the code in the way it was originally, without an argument, it would error without a default ... this might however be a good thing to let happen, as the new code would not necessarily give the correct response